Looking for an old puppet show with squirrels/chipmunks?
Does anyone remember an old puppet show with squirrels/chipmunks? You could visually see their strings. All of the characters had big fluffy cheeks.
One of the characters was named Tippo or something similar and in one episode he has a toothache from eating too many sweets and has nightmares with teeth bouncing up and down in his room (His mom comes to his room and says "Tippo, Tippo, are you alright?") He eventually goes to the dentist.
In another episode a brother meets his brand new baby sister and he is annoyed by her, but ends up liking her by the end of the episode.
I only watched it as a kid on VHS, so i'm not sure if it was ever on tv.
The theme song goes "We are people helping people, showing that with just a little love and a little understanding. We can take our time to care, every moment that we share, we'll be guaranteed to have a happy ending."
I feel it was called something similar to "Giving Friends" or something with neighbor in it?
Endless Google searches and nothing. :<

The standard questions: Country of Origin?  Language?

Also, not an answer, but you can scan through the list on this site and see if a title looks familiar, then check out the theme song for confirmation: http://www.televisiontunes.com/index.php

Ever find your answer I feellike I remember this too, also an episode with a ballon machine & they make to many ballons forthe birthday party and a porcupine pops them and gets scared with a real male man main character

Happy Ending Stories
Youtube linke to theme:



